# Retrofit plain HTML grid to c# grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms

I realize this is a strange/simple question. I have HTML—tables and rows—that make up a grid. I need the resulting grid to look exactly like the HTML does, with data pulled from a `DataTable`.

How should I go about doing that? If I replace the HTML with a `GridView` the result will look different from what I need it to look like. Do I create a custom grid class that spits out tables and rows?

To clarify: I've been given an HTML grid...

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>row 1 col 1</td>
            <td>row 1 col 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 2 col 1</td>
            <td>row 2 col 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

...which I now need to populate with data from a table, and preserve the original HTML.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I answered your question but only realized later you are not talking about a c# desktop application, sorry. Perhaps you should note you are talking about a native HTML table vs an ASP.NET generated Grid

Comment: To be perfectly honest I haven't yet with this project. I've just completed another .net project with a lot of grids and remember how annoying it was to customize the look and feel. I'm wondering what the "industry standard" is in the case where you're given HTML and then need to write the server-side code, preserving the original HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use ASP.Net databinding capabilities, go with a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The markup will look something like this:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Heading</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <asp:Repeater runat="server">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr>
                     <td><%# Eval("SomeFieldName") %></td>
                 </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also build the markup manually in the code-behind by instantiating table/row/cell objects and adding them to the controls collection of the page, control, or parent container control. This tends to be time-consuming but it's a valid option in some cases, such as when you wish to have highly dynamic content that isn't easy to express in a Repeater.

A third option is to mix server markup with client markup, e.g.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Heading</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <% foreach( var obj in someCollection ){ %>
             <tr>
                 <td><%= obj.Property %></td>
             </tr>
         <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The last option is quite similar (albeit more verbose) to [Razor](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) syntax used in ASP.Net MVC views.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is what I was looking for. I haven't played with MVC yet, and I'm coming to the conclusion that for a small intranet project MVC Razor is probably the way to go. But, being a bit lazy, and in a hurry to get the project completed, I may just go with the repeater.

Comment: To continue this for a minute, were I to go with MVC views, where exactly does all the heavy duty logic go? Where is someCollection instantiated?

Comment: Repeater is fine unless you need something elaborate. You will need to bind it to a data source (like a DataTable) in the codebehind, and make sure to turn off ViewState unless you need it (it can become quite large on a grid).

Comment: MVC is a much different paradigm. Your controller sets up a view model, which would have the collection(s) of data. It then passes the model to the view, which would loop through the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet for that would be a repeater.  Link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I agree. With a repeater you will have full control of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a ListView with your HTML table setup as the LayoutTemplate.

quick example:

```
      <asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="server">                                        
            <LayoutTemplate>                                        
                <table id="Table1" cellpadding="1" width="100%" runat="server">                                        
                    <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">                                        
                        <th id="Th1" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left" runat="server">                                        
                           Header1                                        
                        </th>                                        
                        <th id="Th2" style="font-weight: bold; text-align: left" runat="server">                                        
                            Header2                                         
                        </th>                                                                                                            
                    </tr>                                        
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />                                        
                </table>                                        
            </LayoutTemplate>                                        
            <ItemTemplate>                                        
                <tr id="Tr2" runat="server">                                        
                    <td style="text-align: left">                                        
                        <%# Eval("Field1")%>                                        
                    </td>                                        
                    <td style="text-align: left">                                        

                         <%# Eval("Field2")%>                                        
                    </td>                                      

                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```